# Updating the list to have comma at stat and end

Tags: coldfusion

trying to add a starting and ending comma to list of values

I am trying like this

```
<cfscript>
    x = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
    dump(x);
    dump(listqualify(x,"'"));
    dump(javacast(x,"string"));
</cfscript>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/7470dffb0ebcd0fe2d61805631abf914/lucee5?theme=monokai

but ending in error in `javacast`,

i need the third one should be like

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
```

Comment: You are using `javacast` wrong. first argument should be type. like this `javacast("string", x)`

Comment: Are you trying to get something like `"'" & x & "'"`?

Comment: but that will still not wrap the expected output

Comment: If you want the whole output to be wrapped, then you could use `"'" & x & "'"`.

Comment: planning to use within queryparam

Comment: for queryparam you don't need to wrap it. `<cfqueryparam value="#x#" cfsqltype="integer" list="yes">` this should be enough. Just try on a SELECT query and make sure this works.